# Thunderbird unable to refresh inbox ("operation did not succeed")

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail, imap

I recently switched to Thunderbird and at first it worked. However, now I'm always shown an error message like

> The current operation on 'Inbox' did not succeed. The mail server for account myname@gmail.com responded: System Error (Failure).

when clicking on my inbox folder of that account. The same also happens when I click on the "Important" folder of that account or on "All Mail". It does, however, not happen when clicking on "Starred", "Sent Mail", or "Drafts".

I of course googled this problem and read that this happens when IMAP is disabled. However, I didn't touch the settings of my email account before this problem randomly occurred. Disabling and re-enabling IMAP did not help either.

IMAP also does not seem to be disabled as the computer I'm writing this on still downloaded messages from various folders a few minutes ago and a different one is still downloading messages in "Sent Mail" and "Important". The installation of Thunderbird on the other computer shows me the same notifications.

Neither of these installations show my latest messages in my inbox of that account.

However, both installations also are connected to a different Google Account that still works perfectly.

How can this problem be resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of desperation about possibly not reading important mail in time and trying to fix the problem, the problem randomly disappeared. It now both works on new installations and on ones that I haven't touched. I haven't touched my Gmail settings either since I wrote this question. I still sometimes get the error message about All Mail, but regarding Inbox, it's gone. All folders seem to sync just fine now. Before that, there even was a period where messages older than a few days appeared in my inbox on new installations but newer ones didn't.

Conclusion: Gmail is weird (and apparently sometimes really frustrating) and waiting sometimes fixes a problem that occurred with 100% consistency across independent systems for days on end. -.-